# Geth stops working after being fully synced

Tags: go-ethereum, synchronization, peers

I have a Geth server in full mode. It was synced fully and I was using it normally for weeks. Today, I wanted to check the synchronization status, so I used `geth attach` command to enter to the Geth console. I faced to this error:

```
Fatal: Failed to start the JavaScript console: api modules: Post http://127.0.0.1:2555: dial tcp 127.0.0.1:2555: connect: connection refused
```

I did not have any change on this server and as I said, it was working well. Now, when I want to run Geth again, it stops working with the below output:

```
WARN [05-09|16:30:02.576] Sanitizing cache to Go's GC limits       provided=16384 updated=5220
INFO [05-09|16:30:02.579] Maximum peer count                       ETH=50 LES=0 total=50
INFO [05-09|16:30:02.580] Smartcard socket not found, disabling    err="stat /run/pcscd/pcscd.comm: no such file or directory"
INFO [05-09|16:30:02.582] Starting peer-to-peer node               instance=Geth/v1.9.12-stable-b6f1c8dc/linux-amd64/go1.13.8
INFO [05-09|16:30:02.582] Allocated trie memory caches             clean=1.27GiB dirty=1.27GiB
INFO [05-09|16:30:02.582] Allocated cache and file handles         database=/mnt/geth/chaindata cache=2.55GiB handles=524288
```

What is the problem for? May you help me please?